# How to know the lib directory of a project?

Tags: eclipse

I want to copy some jar and dll files into the lib directory of a project. How to know this directory ?

Comment: What do you mean with "how to know this directory"? If you defined the project structure, then you know, where this directory is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're used to some other IDE - which one?  Eclipse doesn't have a defined place for dependent jars - you point at them individually, so they can be scattered all over.  You can make a lib directory yourself and put everything there - it's up to you.